# Publishing messages to ActiveMQ using Gatling

Tags: scala, jms, activemq-classic, performance-testing, gatling

I have been using **Gatling** to publish messages to ActiveMq server. I get **"java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid username:  null or empty"**  tho I use valid username and password. Here is my test code and the exception were thrown. Any inputs on how to fix this will be of help.

```
import io.gatling.core.Predef.Simulation
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.jms.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.config.Credentials
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory
import javax.jms._ 
    class WebProducer extends  Simulation{
      val jmsUsername:String="userName"
      val jmsPwd:String="Password"
      val jmsConfig = jms
        .connectionFactoryName("ConnectionFactory")
        .url("ssl://message01-dev.platform.net:61617")
        .credentials(jmsUsername,jmsPwd)
        .disableAnonymousConnect
        .contextFactory(classOf[org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory].getName)
         .listenerCount(1)
        .usePersistentDeliveryMode
        .receiveTimeout(6000)

      val scn = scenario("JMS DSL test").repeat(1) {
        exec(jms("req reply testing").
          reqreply
          .queue("YourJMSQueueName")
          .replyQueue("YourJMSQueueName")
          .textMessage("payload To be posted")
          .property("company_id", "1234598776665")
          .property("event_type","EntityCreate")
          .property("event_target_entity_type","Account")    
        )
      }
      setUp(scn.inject(atOnceUsers(1)))
        .protocols(jmsConfig)         
    }
```

Following is the exception was thrown :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid username:  null or empty
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got this working adding two things :

```
-  .disableAnonymousConnect after  .credentials(jmsUsername,jmsPwd)
-  .replyQueue(jmsQueueName) after .queue(jmsQueueName)
```

I edited the above code to reflect the same. 
Happy Gatling !