# JMS-Loadtest using Gatling: unable to initialize ContextFactory of IBM MQ

Tags: ibm-mq, gatling, scala-gatling

I'm implementing a load test scenario against a IBM MQ with Gatling. 
The setup is basically the same as mentioned [here](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/jms/)

Problem: I'm not able to initialize the required `ContextFactory` with IBM MQ - which should be `com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory`. 
The `WMQInitialContextFactory` cannot be found.

But my `build.sbt` is containing the IBM MQ dependency correctly (being successfully retrieved by our internal Nexus :

```
"com.ibm.mq" % "com.ibm.mq" % "8.0.0.3"
```

My gatling scenario:

```
package com.myawesomecompany.loadtest

import com.ibm.mq._
import com.ibm.mq.jms.MQConnectionFactory
import com.ibm.mq.jms.JMSMQ_Messages
import com.ibm.msg.client.wmq.common.CommonConstants
import io.gatling.core.Predef._
import io.gatling.core.scenario.Simulation
import io.gatling.jms.Predef._
import javax.jms._

import scala.concurrent.duration._

class JMSLoadTest extends Simulation {

  val jmsConfiguration = jms
    .connectionFactoryName("ConnectionFactory")
    .url("devmq01.company.dmz")
    .credentials("mqm", "mqm")

  .contextFactory(classOf[com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContrextFactory].getName) 
  .listenerCount(1)
  .usePersistentDeliveryMode  

 val scn = scenario("Load testing GPRSForwarder").repeat(1) {
exec(jms("testing GPRSForwarder...").reqreply
  .queue("COMPANY.TEST.QUEUE")
  .textMessage("00001404020611100E033102C20EBB51CC1C036EFFFF00010002323802000200FE05001400000000FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF040010038B0D6912EB10CE070206110F37298C")
  .jmsType("test_jms_type")
    )
  }  

 setUp(scn.inject(rampUsersPerSec(10) to 1000 during (2 minutes)))
    .protocols(jmsConfiguration)


}
```

The setup is equivalent to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37980175/publishing-messages-to-activemq-using-gatling) - but instead of using `ActiveMQInitalContextFactory`, I'm forced to use the "counterpart" of IBM MQ.

According to [official docks](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0502_woolf/0502_woolf.html) the `WMQInitialContextFactory` should be in `com.ibm.mq.jms.context` but it is not. Ore is there some constant in `CommonConstants` which I can use to initialize a `ContextFactory` ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Josh. To get sure, I've made a wildcart import in order to have all sources of `com.ibm.mqjms._` from ibm mq allclient. I've looked for the Java-All package you've mentionied but also this one didn't include `WMQInitialContextFacgory`

Comment: Do not use WMQInitialContextFactory. See comments below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Problem: I'm not able to initialize the required ContextFactory with
>   IBM MQ - which should be
>   com.ibm.mq.jms.context.WMQInitialContextFactory. The
>   WMQInitialContextFactory cannot be found.

Do not use WMQInitialContextFactory.  It was an MQ SupportPac someone created where they wanted to use MQ as the JNDI repository.  It is not a good idea plus the SupportPac does not support any form of security (i.e. SSL/TLS or security exit).

You should use a file based MQ JNDI.  Here's a basic example:

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Queue;
import javax.jms.QueueConnection;
import javax.jms.QueueConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.QueueSender;
import javax.jms.QueueSession;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import com.ibm.mq.MQException;

/**
 * Program Name
 *  TestJMS01
 *
 * Description
 *  This java JMS class will connect to a remote queue manager
 *  using JNDI and put a message to a queue.
 *
 * Sample Command Line Parameters
 *  -x myQCF -q dev.test.q -f C:\JNDI-Directory\roger\mqjndi
 *
 *  Sample MQ JNDI Commands:
 *    DEFINE QCF(myQCF) QMANAGER(MQA1) CHANNEL(TEST.CHL) HOSTNAME(127.0.0.1) PORT(1415) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
 *    DEFINE Q(dev.test.q) QUEUE(TEST1) QMANAGER(MQA1) TARGCLIENT(JMS) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
 *
 * @author Roger Lacroix, Capitalware Inc.
 */
public class TestJMS01
{
   private static final String JNDI_CONTEXT = "com.sun.jndi.fscontext.RefFSContextFactory";

   private QueueConnectionFactory cf;
   private Queue q;
   private Hashtable<String,String> params = null;
   private String userID = "tester";
   private String password = "mypwd";

   public TestJMS01() throws NamingException
   {
      super();
   }

   /**
    * Make sure the required parameters are present.
    * @return true/false
    */
   private boolean allParamsPresent()
   {
      return (params.containsKey("-x") && params.containsKey("-q") && params.containsKey("-f"));
   }

   /**
    * Extract the command-line parameters and initialize the MQ variables.
    * @param args
    * @throws IllegalArgumentException
    */
   private void init(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException
   {
      params = new Hashtable<String,String>(10);
      if (args.length > 0 && (args.length % 2) == 0)
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2)
         {
            params.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }

      if (allParamsPresent())
      {
         Hashtable<String,Object> env = new Hashtable<String,Object>();
         env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, JNDI_CONTEXT);
         env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "file:/"+(String) params.get("-f"));

         try
         {
            Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);

            cf = (QueueConnectionFactory) ctx.lookup((String) params.get("-x"));
            q = (Queue) ctx.lookup((String) params.get("-q"));
         }
         catch (NamingException e)
         {
            System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
         }
      }
      else
      {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
   }

   /**
    * Test the connection to the queue manager.
    * @throws MQException
    */
   private void testConn() throws JMSException
   {
      QueueConnection connection = null;
      QueueSession session = null;

      try
      {
         connection = cf.createQueueConnection(userID, password);
         connection.start();

         session = connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);

         sendMsg(session);
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
         System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
         System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            session.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            System.err.println("session.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            connection.stop();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            System.err.println("connection.stop() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }

         try
         {
            connection.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            System.err.println("connection.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * Send a message to a queue.
    * @throws MQException
    */
   private void sendMsg(QueueSession session) throws JMSException
   {
      QueueSender sender = null;

      try
      {
         TextMessage msg = session.createTextMessage();
         msg.setText("Nice simple test. Time in 'ms' is  -> " + System.currentTimeMillis());
         // msg.setJMSReplyTo(tq);
         // msg.setJMSDeliveryMode( DeliveryMode.NON_PERSISTENT);

         System.out.println("Sending request to " + q.getQueueName());
         System.out.println();

         sender = session.createSender(q);
         sender.send(msg);
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
         System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
         System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      finally
      {
         try
         {
            sender.close();
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
            System.err.println("sender.close() : " + ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         }
      }
   }

   /**
    * main line
    * @param args
    */
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      try
      {
         TestJMS01 tj = new TestJMS01();
         tj.init(args);
         tj.testConn();
      }
      catch (IllegalArgumentException e)
      {
         System.err.println("Usage: java TestJMS01 -x QueueConnectionFactoryName -q JMS_Queue_Name -f path_to_MQ_JNDI");
         System.exit(1);
      }
      catch (NamingException ex)
      {
         System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (JMSException e)
      {
         System.err.println("getLinkedException()=" + e.getLinkedException());
         System.err.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
         System.err.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Roger, thanks a lot for your feedback. So you mean, instead of using the `jms`-configuration as provied by the `DSL` of Gatling just to implement a custom connection factory (as you've provided in your example) and pass this to the setup of gatling?

Comment: Another question: what do I have to pass here `"file:/"+(String) params.get("-f"));`? The JNDI commands like the examples in your snippet, i.e.  `DEFINE QCF(myQCF) QMANAGER(MQA1) CHANNEL(TEST.CHL) HOSTNAME(127.0.0.1) PORT(1415) TRANSPORT(CLIENT) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)
 *    DEFINE Q(dev.test.q) QUEUE(TEST1) QMANAGER(MQA1) TARGCLIENT(JMS) FAILIFQUIESCE(YES)`

Comment: 'Define QCF(myQCF)...' command is done via the JMSAdmin console program or you can use MQ Explorer to add objects to your MQ JNDI repository.  See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21614256

Comment: Roger, one another question: I'm having issues adding objects to my MQ JNDI repository using IBM MQ Explorer. As far as I understood I simply have to go to JMS-Administered Objects/Add Initial Context (...) as explained [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023212&aid=1) at Chapter 3 (Page 16). I'm succesfully able to connect to the Queue Manager and I'm seing all the existent Queues. I didn't create a `.bindings`- file because this is being generated by MQ Explorer, right? After click on finish I'm getting this:

Comment: `"The object myQCF could not be created because you do not have authority to create objects ore there is no connection to the context"` But being able to connect to the Queue Manager it shouldn't be a user authorization issue?

Answer (score -1):

Not directly related to your problem, but `JMSToolBox` with its scripting feature, is a tool that allows to perform bulk/load test on IBM MQ.

With it you can define a `script`, composed of `steps`, that will read a `template` with `variable` placeholders and repeatedly put messages in one or multiple destinations. It can also directly read saved messages from a directory etc.

You can download it from SourceForge [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jmstoolbox/)
Documentation of the script feature [is here](https://sourceforge.net/p/jmstoolbox/wiki/Scripts/)

Comment: Your answer has nothing to do with the question other other self promote your tool on SourceForge.

Comment: thanks for your input, Roger - but I'll stick to Gatling ;.)

Comment: Roger, sorry I mistook your Name.